# Can't install Ubuntu 17.10 with i9 processor on x299 motherboard

Tags: system-installation

I just build a new computer with the intention of dual booting into Ubuntu 17.10.  I have an i9-7900x processor and the ASRock Fatal1ty X299 Pro Gaming motherboard and 32 gigs of RAM.  However, it encounters multiple errors and will not boot.  I have read several people having issues with an i9 processor running linux.  Is there any way to make this run without buying new hardware?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** Could be a hardware issue: does memtest work?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet.  But, all 32 gigs are recognized in the bios.